# Yii2 Codeception: How to wipe database when running individual suites?

Tags: unit-testing, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, codeception

How do I wipe the database in the [yii2-app-advanced](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced) template when running individual suites (e.g. "backend")? For example:

```
./vendor/bin/codecept run -- -c backend
```

*(Note: This approach is [officially documented](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/275080a1f39928514f0c16e00c313e8f31a6b48a/docs/guide/start-testing.md).)*

I am trying to create some unit tests where records are inserted as part of a test. These records have `unique` constraints on some of the attributes. These test pass correctly on the first run, but if I run the same command again it will fail (because the database was not wiped and the records from the previous run still exist).

Interestingly enough if I run all tests at once (backend + common + frontend) using the following command:

```
./vendor/bin/codecept run
```

Then everything will run fine as the database will have actually been cleared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the solution. It turns out the yii2-advanced-app documentation is incorrect/incomplete/outdated.

Individual suites should be run like this:

```
./vendor/bin/codecept run -c backend
```

The difference was omitting the double dash (`--`).
Now everything works fine and the database is properly wiped after each run.

Answer (score 1):

Your tests should clean up after itself. You may use `_before()` and `_after()` methods to ensure database state before and after every test execution.

```
protected function _before() {
    parent::_before();
    Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->truncateTable('{{%my_table}}');
}

protected function _after() {
    Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->truncateTable('{{%my_table}}');
    parent::_after();
}
```

You may also try to use `setUpBeforeClass()` and `tearDownAfterClass()` to trigger some events only once before/after all class tests execution.

Comment: The tests do clear up after themselves, but like I said only when I run all the tests and not when I run say the backend tests only. Anyhow this solution will do for now.